# Erroneous text by pandas while using to_csv function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file which has a list of stock symbols for different companies. I need to add token to each symbol and export the dataframe to a csv using to_csv function. I know how do it and have been doing it for long.
But a weird bug is bugging the program. Input csv file has a stock symbol SMRUTHIORG which is the correct symbol. But my python script somehow reads it as SMRUTHIORGÂ  with an extra weird A in the end and thus it fails to map to a stock code. I have no idea where this weird A comes from. I guess it is have a problem in decoding. Here is my code:

```
    import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('../list_of_script.csv')
df1 = df[['trendlyne_symbols','nse_instrument_token']]
df1 = df1.assign(token = '')
df1 = df1.drop(['nse_instrument_token'], axis=1)
df1 = df1.dropna()
print(df1)

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    print(f'working on row number {index} of df1')
    for index2, row2 in df.iterrows():
        if row['trendlyne_symbols'] == row2['nse_tradingsymbol']:
            row['token'] = row2['nse_instrument_token']
            print('match found...')
            break
        elif row['trendlyne_symbols'] == row2['bse_tradingsymbol']:
            row['token'] = row2['bse_instrument_token']
            print('match found')
            break

df1.to_csv('output_tokens.csv', index=False)
print(df1.tail())
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it could have to do with some characters that are not recognized. Maybe specifying the encoding could help

```
pd.read_csv('../list_of_script.csv',encoding="utf_8")
```

If you could provide the relevant part of your csv file, I could try to reproduce your error.